# Network Policy - Restricting Egress From Some Namespaces But Allowing Other Namespace

Tags: kubernetes, policy

Suppose I have these `ns`

```
nginx-master - Running my Ingress controller
monitoring   - Running Prometheus, Grafana
```

```
app1-project (Parent)
  app1-dev
  app1-qa

app2-project(Parent)
  app2-dev
  app2-qa
```

I basically wanted to send traffic (ingress/egress) from `nginx-master` and monitoring to app1-project and app2-project (Propagated to their respective children)

However, blocking any (ingress/egress) traffic from app1-project and app2-project to each other

Answer (score 1):

Below config should do the trick for you

First, create labels on the namespaces with `project: ingress` and `project: monitoring` respectively.

Then use the below manifest.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-network-policy
  namespace: app1-project
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: ingress
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: monitoring
```

Having empty egress will deny all egress https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-egress-traffic